# Can't use Spring security /logout resource

Tags: angular, spring, spring-security, angular-httpclient

I have a spring security app. When i try to log out via my angular front-end, I will get a 404 (Not found).

I have tried many spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configurations, and i get a 404 with all of them. I am using POST to make my request.(see below)

```
logout() {
    this.http.post('/logout', "").pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.app.authenticated.next(false);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Using Postman, i get a 403 (forbidden) when trying to reach the resource

Comment: Please post the code that caused the error

Comment: Show your Spring Security configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact what you need is just to add a logout success handler

```
  @Component
public class LogoutSuccess implements LogoutSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
        try {
            httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
            // you can add more codes here when the user successfully logs
            // out,
            // such as updating the database for last active.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            e = null;
        }
    }

    httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);

}

}
```

and add a success handler to your security config

```
http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().logout().logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccess).deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(false).permitAll();
```

or you can also try this :

```
 logout() {
    this.http.post('/logout').pipe(
      finalize(() => {
        this.app.authenticated.next(false);
      })
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Please up vote the answer if it has resolved your issue. Thanks !